# Button inside collection view cell not responding to layout changes

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view cell with a button inside the cell.  When I tap the cell (using `.touchUpInside`), I don't see the layout changes that are supposed to occur.

Here's the action method that gets called. I know that it is appropriately getting called because I get the log `button tapped touch down`.

My collection view is using a compositional layout and a `UIDiffableDataSource`.

```swift
    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        print("button tapped touch down")
        self.button.isSpinning = true

    }
```

The above action sets the property `isSpinning` in the view, which is supposed to trigger the animation of the activity indicator and the background color change. The `SmallCellButton` is a class that's a UIView with a transparent button on top of it. It works completely fine when used in other situations than this collection view scenario.

```swift
class SmallCellButton : UIView {

    ...

    var isSpinning : Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if isSpinning {
                print("should be spinning")
                self.label.isHidden = true
                self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                self.activityIndicator.alpha = 1

                self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
                self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            } else {
                print("should stop spinning")
                self.label.isHidden = false
                self.activityIndicator.alpha = 0
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()


                self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I get the log of `"should be spinning"`, but I don't ever see the layout changes after the `.touchUpInside` event. I can step through all the layout code using the debugger, but no visual changes appear.

If I move the layout code from `isSpinning` to an overrided `isHighlighted` property, the layout code executes AND visually displays. If I move it to an overrided `isSelected` property, then it does not visually display, but it does execute.

Comment: call `self.layoutIfNeeded()` after changes

Comment: @jawadAli , layout still does not update

Comment: The `UICollectionViewCell` class will remove all animations when it's `prepareForReuse` method is called, that might be quashing animation on the activity indicator.

Comment: @mfessenden astute point. Issue is, none of the layout code is getting visually shown. The label doesn't hide, and background color doesn't change. I commented out animation code to see if anything changed, but it did not.